# Crash in Google ads

Tags: android, crash, admob, crashlytics

Does Google ads requires any run time permissions? I am getting following crash report in Crashlytics. Please help me to solve this issue.

```html
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10124 does not have android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS.
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.bindService(ActivityManagerNative.java:3902)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1322)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1291)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:604)
       at wn.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):37)
       at vq.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):37)
       at vp.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):13)
       at un.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):48)
       at un.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):96)
       at so.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):34)
       at sv.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):6)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at xg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@14799046@14.7.99 (040306-223214910):5)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, Google AdMob doesn't require such permissions. This permission is intended to be used by system apps only. However, if you are using personalized ads to users then AdMob collects user personal data (e.g. deviceId) from cookies or other sources. For this purpose, Google Play Service should have that required permission and developers not intended to access those personal data.

Though you have not provided your AdMob implementation detailed source code, it's not possible to identify exactly if this crash comes because of AdMob only. But if you are trying to use any sensitive user personal data (e.g deviceId used by AdMob) which you shouldn't, then this crash might arise. Except developing system apps, you cannot invoke the above permission to resolve such crash. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS) is the official documentation about the permission:

> Allows an application to update device statistics. Not for use by
>   third-party applications.